# finding time and memory inefficiencies in my program

Tags: python-3.x, memory, memory-management, time

I need to find time and memory inefficiencies in this program. I've tried several things: changing the variable names and also changed the code to delete the for-loops. These things made the program not work unfortunately. Can anyone help?

```
import sys
def longest(doc):

infile = open(doc, "r")
text = infile.read()

longest_seq = []
current_seq = []
current_start = ""
first_letters = [""]
for word in text.split():
    current_start = word[0]
    if current_start == first_letters[-1]:
        # same first letter as previous word
        current_seq.append(word)
    elif current_start != first_letters[-1]:
        # done with the current sequence
        current_seq = [word]

    first_letters.append(word[0])

    if len(longest_seq) < len(current_seq):
        longest_seq = current_seq

infile.close()
return longest_seq


def main(argv):
    if len(argv) != 2:
    print("Usage: {} File".format(argv[0]), file=sys.stderr)
    exit(-1)

   seq = longest(argv[1])
   slength = len(longest(argv[1]))

print("longest sequence of consecutive words starting with the same letter:")
print("\'{}\'".format(' '.join(seq)))
print("length: {}\n".format(slength))



if __name__ == "__main__":
main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Please include a description of what is to be achieved by an execution of the program.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of `longest()`.

Comment: What do you build `first_letters` for?